# Exception in two line Xerces program

Tags: c++, windows, xerces

The following code gives me an exception on the `XMLFormatTarget` line, but if I change the string from `"C:/test.xml"` to `"test.xml"` it works fine.

```
// test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp>
#include <xercesc/framework/LocalFileFormatTarget.hpp>

using namespace xercesc;

int main()
{
    XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();

    XMLFormatTarget *formatTarget = new LocalFileFormatTarget("C:/test.xml"); 

    return 0;
}
```

[edit]
Xerces exception is:

> Error Message: unable to open file
>   'C:\test.xml'

Windows exception is:

> Access is denied

Comment: Please help us to help you: what is the exception you got ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you don't have sufficient permissions to write to `C:\`. In such a case, Xerces might report the error throwing an exception.

An `Access Denied` exception is typically what we could expect if you try to write to a system directory without administrator credentials.

---

Maybe it has also something to do with the directory separators:

```
XMLFormatTarget *formatTarget = new LocalFileFormatTarget("C:\\test.xml");
```

On Windows, directory separators are backslashes "\". Some libraries don't care (and I never used Xerces, so I can't tell). In `C` and `C++`, backslash is also an *escape character* and so you must **double** it if you want a litteral "\" in your string.

Also, telling us what was the exception you got would help us even more.

---

Not directly related, but from your code, it seems you never `delete` `formatTarget`. I assume this is sample code, but if it is not, you should add the following line to your code:

```
delete formatTarget;
```

Or use a **scoped pointer** instead:

```
boost::scoped_ptr<XMLFormatTarget> formatTarget(new LocalFileFormatTarget("C:\\test.xml"));
```

To avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I don't knwo Xerxes either, but what's wrong with `LocalFileFormatTarget formatTarget("C:\\test.xml");`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply ereOn, i still get an exception with "C:\\test.xml". I am aware formatTarget needs to be freed, i just wanted to post the least possible amount of code to reproduce the problem. Ill post back with exception.

Comment: It's not that "some libraries" don't care, WinAPI itself don't care and for the most part you can use \ and / interchangeably on Windows.

Comment: @sbi: There is nothing wrong with the double backslashes, that's my point. Perhaps you misread the question or my answer ? @sbk: I've seen many libraries that *do* care. Maybe those libraries are badly-designed, but that's another topic. Anyway, since I don't know Xerces, I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Updated original question with exception.

Comment: @Gungho: I already had updated my answer with another possibility ;) And it seems I was right: you probably have not enough permissions to write directly under `C:\`.

Comment: Yes! it was a problem writing to C:/ under Windows Vista, no problems writing to other paths, or writing to C:/ under Windows XP. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try transcoding the filename:

```
// Convert the path into Xerces compatible XMLCh*. 
XMLCh *tempFilePath = XMLString::transcode(filePath.c_str()); 

// Specify the target for the XML output. 
XMLFormatTarget *formatTarget = new LocalFileFormatTarget(tempFilePath);
```

as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897317/writing-xml-with-xerces-3-0-1-and-c-on-windows/2897419#2897419) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897317/writing-xml-with-xerces-3-0-1-and-c-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

If you use only `test.xml` you specify a path relative to the current working directory (usually where the program was started from). So if your program is not directly on your C: drive, the two runs could point to different files. The `C:\test.xml` could have an error, but `C:\Path\to\your\program\test.xml` correct, so the latter gives you no exception.

Anyway, as ereOn said, it would help if we knew which exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply king_nak, the file test.xml does not exist for either the working or non working example. this bit of code is a part of a program that actually creates test.xml, and populates it.